# using resx file to raplace labels

Tags: asp.net, localization

hii all ,
  I want to replace my labels in aspx page to user friendly language. i have read about .resx files. but i am not getting correct flow of how to do it..could you plz help... I

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/localization.aspx

Answer (score 0):

its concept of localization and globlization so just go through this : [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx)

[ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)

Comment: thnk you verry much!!
 i got it.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net provider easy way to resolve your problem. 
 An exemple:

```
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralSampleText" runat="server" 
                    Text="<%$ Resources:default, theSampleText %>"></asp:Literal>
```

So, you have to set `theSampleText`  in your resx file, for fr,us or other language.